# SOC2: how would a sole-person business comply with pull request requirement?

Tags: compliance

My very superficial understanding is that for SOC2 compliance, every change must be reviewed so that no one person can make production changes without someone else being involved.

How would that work in a company with one person? Similar if you have two people but sometimes one person is sick. Are you meant to just not ship changes until they are able to work again?

I assume there is some caveat that would allow the single developer to continue functioning. What is that caveat?

Comment: Apologies if this is off-topic. first result on google for "soc2 stackexchange" so I figured it was my best bet.

Comment: Why are you attempting to undergo the SOC2 auditing process if you're a sole-person business? You won't be able to comply with many of the requirements, or they would be not applicable. It doesn't make any sense

Comment: Well I'm not actually a sole developer business, but close enough that it was a simpler question to ask for what I was worried about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, SOC2 will NEVER dictate what you must do for compliance.  Generally, a SOC2 auditor will ask you what your process is for the Software Development Lifecycle (SDLC), ask for the documentation, get data to support that you're following it, and report whether you're following it.

With that in mind, what does your SDLC process documentation say?  For example, for a one-person development shop, I might create a process document describing how the code is secured, how version control is in place, and that it is run through a SAST tool to look for potential security issues and the SAST findings are corrected before release. I would probably add something to the document stating that a formal code review/code push process will be implemented as the team grows.

I ran into similar situations with small Operations teams.  Obtaining SOC2 attestation is about documenting how you work and providing data to prove you follow your documentation.

Comment: Thanks a ton for that clarification!